# How establish precedence of operations in Django Templates?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In my Django I have a model as such:

```
class myModel(models.model):
    a = models.TextField()
```

In my views.py file, I have this:

```
myDict = {
    "A": myModel(a="X"),
    "B": myModel(a="Y"),
    "C": myModel(a="Z"),
}
```

I have created the following template tag:

```
@register.filter
def get_item(dictionary, key):
    return dictionary[key]
```

In my Template, I loop through the keys with myKey. I have the following. It works:

```
{% for myKey in myDict %}
    {{myDict|get_item:myKey}}
{% endfor %}
```

I can tell it works because it prints myDict[myKeys] on the webpage.

However, when I want to access the attribute a of myDict["myKey"], it fails:

```
{% for myKey in myDict %}
    {{myDict|get_item:myKey.a}}
{% endfor %}
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Failed lookup for key [a] in u'A'
```

The problem is that when I say myDict|get_item:myKey.a, I mean (myDict|get_item:myKey).a but it thinks I mean myDict|get_item:(myKey.a)

How do I tell it that the the precedence of the : operator is higher . without using parenthesis (which Django templates don't allow)?

Comment: What about iterating over the dict in an [usual manner](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for): `{% for key, value in myDict.items %}{{ value.a }}{% endfor %}`?

Comment: I recommend @alecxe's answer above. You could also do `{% with myDict|get_item:myKey as item %}{{ item.a }}{% endwith %}`

Comment: The order of that iteration over myDict is relevant. I want to go in a very specific order that is not captured in the above solution (or even properly by my original question).

Comment: @SaqibAli, Python dictionary does not guarantee the order of keys. How about using [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need custom filter. Just use [`dict.values`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) (or [`dict.itervalues`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.itervalues) if you use Python 2.x):

```
{% for myModel in myDict.values %}
    {{ myModel.a }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `with` tag:

```
{% with myDict|get_item:myKey as item %}
    {{ item.a }}
{% endwith %}
```